Can number of steps in whatsapp flows be defined dynamically?
Is there a way in whatsapp-api to dynamically specify number of steps in the flow?
What i mean is, I would like the user to answer using an interactive dropdown list, let's say 8 out of 10 results.
Based on that number of results i would set up an interactive flow in the next step that will basically iterate through each of the selected components and ask for further details.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You cannnot generate screens dynamicly. But you might add 10 or 20 fields and set their visibility to false and give their name from your server.. Depending on the thing you want to do; you can set their visibility on your server with data-exchange.

You can control the navigation of the Flow using endpoint data. So you can navigate to screens dynamically based on user selection, eg: if user selects 3 items, you can navigate to a predefined screen 3 times with different data each time
Docs page for Flows endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/guides/implementingyourflowendpoint
